# Save File Tkinter Different Columns

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, savefiledialog

I am developing a GUI and now I'm trying to make a function to save a file from a list in tkinter, I want to save from two different list, the problem is I cannot make the list to stack side by side like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qklin.png), is there any way to do that in tkinter??

This is my function, I do not post the GUI part because I don't think it's necessary

```
def savefile(self):
    self.a = np.arange(0,10,1)
    self.b = np.arange(1,11,1)
    fileout = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
    text2save = ('\n'.join(map(str, self.a))) + ('\n'.join(map(str, self.b)))
    fileout.write(text2save)
    fileout.close()
```

The code above will save the list but not side by side like I intended to do, instead it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB3VK.png)

Thanks for the help!!

Edit : If I may add another question, is there any way I can save the file to another extension type such as xlsx or docx??

Comment: Try: `text2save = '\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str,x)) for x in zip(self.a,self.b))`.

Comment: Oh yes that works perfectly!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine 2 lists into single list using `zip` function.  So modify the `text2save = ...` to:

```
text2save = '\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str,x)) for x in zip(self.a,self.b))
```